# New tab chrome extension don't focus on open

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a New tab chrome extension (Chrome's "New Tab" replacing, a bit like [momentumdash](https://momentumdash.com)), everything works well, but, when i open a new tab (`Cmd` + `T`), the browser input is in the url/search field of Chrome, and not on my extension.

Is that possible to focus an input immediately when a new tab extension is opened?

Code is available here: https://github.com/rdlh/eva

Comment: Yes it is! Sorry dont saw this answer, thanks @wOxxOm , I will remove my question

Comment: Yep, took me several attempts to find it.

Comment: Still a sick chrome update, bad news for my new tab idea..

Comment: Here's an idea: [add a Chrome hotkey](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands) that will open your extension page. Of course this will be useful for a [much] smaller amount of users.